# WebClient DownloadFileAsync File Exists

Tags: c#, webclient, downloadfileasync

Is there a recommended method for using DownloadFileAsyc and determining if the file exists? It seems that the only way I can tell is on the DownloadCompleted event the error property has a 404 error in it, and the there's a file created that is 0 bytes.

It would be nice to have a more deterministic method.

Comment: Have you considered using HttpWebRequest and making a HEAD request? This way you can get the status and response headers w/o actually downloading the file initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris T had the right answer. (or at least good enough for me).